# Make sure only one animation is being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am running this animation on `$(window).scroll()` and it works fine for the most part.

```
$('#el').animate({ left: toMove }, 500);
```

The problem is if the user scrolls too fast, two animations will fire and the second animation will fire before the first one has moved far enough. How can I make sure there is only one animation at any given time and then the other animations will follow? I need the element to animate left FULLY any other animations run but I need them all to run. I tried using `.queue()` but couldn't find the right solution with it.

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: You should debounce onscroll event by using a timeout e.g. BUT you could use instead: `$('#el:not(:animated)').animate({ left: toMove }, 500);`

Comment: You'd have really better to provide a concrete sample replicating your issue, a jsFiddle maybe, and anyway, ***you have*** to post all relevant code in question?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function like this to smooth things up:

```
$('#el').stop(true, false).animate({ left: toMove }, 500);
```

The `stop` function, when calling like that will clear the animation queue for any waiting animation, as well as stop the current animation if any.

## Edit

If you want the animation to end before animating again you just need to call `.stop(true, true)` instead

Comment: I think `.stop()` is quite enough

Comment: it won't clear the animation queue, you could emit the second false though

Comment: As i'm guessing issue, this wouldn't fix it

Comment: Might not be understanding your solution fully but I don't want to stop the current animation. I Need it to animate the full length before the next animation runs. Then when the current animation is done, move to the next animation.

Comment: Meant animation not element. There is only one element animating.